# Generar una matriz de decimales aleatorias

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando generar una matriz aleatoria con decimales en un rango en especifico (-100 a 100)
El problema es que solo me esta generando decimales positivos de 0 a 1. como podría solucionar esto?

Este es mi código:

```
        double[,] matriz = new double[c, f];
        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            for (int J = 0; J < f; J++)
            {
                matriz[i, J] = aleatorio.NextDouble();
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < c; x++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < f; j++)
            {
               // Console.WriteLine("--------");
                Console.Write("|    " + matriz[x, j] + "    |");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: miraste la documentacion de Random??? es exactamente lo que hace la funcion aleatoria...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo hacer una función propia para este cálculo:

```
public double RandomDecimales(int limiteInferior, int limiteSuperior)
{
    Random r = new Random();           
    var parteDecimal = r.NextDouble();
    var parteEntera = r.Next(limiteInferior, limiteSuperior);
    var numero = 0.0;

    if (parteEntera == limiteSuperior || parteEntera == limiteInferior)
    {
        numero = parteEntera;
    }
    else
    {
        numero = (parteEntera >= 0) ?
                  parteEntera + parteDecimal :
                  parteEntera - parteDecimal;
    
    }

    return numero;          
}
```

En esta función usamos la **clase** **Random** para generar la parte entera del número y la parte decimal del número. La función recibe dos parámetros enteros que representan el límite inferior y el límite superior del rango en que queremos obtener el número aleatorio. La parte decimal la obtenemos usando:

```
var parteDecimal = r.NextDouble();
```

La **función** **NextDouble** nos devuelve un número aleatorio entre **0** y **1**.

Para obtener la parte entera hacemos:

```
var parteEntera = r.Next(limiteInferior, limiteSuperior);
```

Donde obtendremos un número entre los rangos definidos.

Una vez obtenida la parte entera y la decimal preguntamos si la parte entera es igual al **limiteInferior** que en tu caso es **-100** o igual al **limiteSuperior** que en tu caso es **100**, de ser igual a uno de estos dos valores pues retornamos solamente la parte entera.

De no ser igual al **limiteInferior** o **limiteSuperior** la parte entera, entonces preguntamos si la parte entera es positiva, de ser positiva sumamos la parte entera con la parte decimal, y retornamos esa suma, la cual sería el número aleatorio.

De ser negativa la parte entera entonces restamos la parte entera con la decimal y retornamos esa resta, la cual será el número aleatorio.

Cuando hagamos la función la llamamos de esta forma:

```
var numeroAleatorio = RandomDecimales(-100, 101);
```

Fíjate que ponemos **101** en el límite superior de esta forma garantizamos que se incluya el **100**, el límite inferior se queda en **-100**, ya que el límite inferior se incluye por defecto.

Answer (score 0):

Como comentan arriba, random() te entrega un entero entre [0,RandMax] no decimales.

Entonces basta con añadir una semilla a rand:
srand (time(NULL));

Casteamos a double y hacemos las operaciones para obtener un "decimal aleatorio"
seed = ((double)rand()) / ((double)RAND_MAX) * 9.9 + 0.1;